# Add onEachFeature function to existing layer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

I have a GeoJSON layer that comes from a fetch function in another js module. I call this layer through an await function and therefore, I cannot use L.geojson(data, {onEachFeature: onEachfeature}). I need to add the `onEachFeature` function after loading the data.

I tried to add it through an empty GeoJSON but it doesn't work since I'm calling my layer's attributes in the `onEachFeature` function.

Does anyone know the solution?

Code :

```
// Load the layer

const communes_lyr = await getLayer4('communes');

// Set the style (ideally, a function like this but for onEachFeature would be great!)

communes_lyr.setStyle(com_style)

// Create an empty geojson to add the oneachfeature function

var empty_com = L.geoJSON(false, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, communes_lyr) {
    communes_lyr.bindPopup(feature.properties.COMMUNE + "<br>" + "<br>"
      + "Pollution lumineuse = " + feature.properties.intensity + "%" + "<br>"
      + "Population = " + feature.properties.POPULATION + " habitants" + "<br>"
      + "Superficie = " + feature.properties.superficie + "km²")
  }
}).addTo(map);

// Add the empty layer with the function to my layer

communes_lyr.addData(empty_com);
```

Comment: Instances of `L.GeoJSON` do have a `eachFeature()` method, inherited from `L.LayerGroup`. It's in the API documentation.

Comment: I know this, but my issue is more about knowing how to call it outside of the L.geojson instance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leverage the `eachFeature()` method of `L.GeoJSON`. You might not see an `eachFeature()` method in [the `L.GeoJSON` documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-method) at first, since that method is implemented by `L.GeoJSON`'s parent class `L.LayerGroup`.

Usage is similar than [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach.html): the parameter to the method must be a function (or function reference). And that function will receive a `L.Layer` as its first parameter, e.g.

```
var group = L.geoJson(/* stuff */);

group.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer.bindPopup('Hello');
});
```

Note how that's equivalent to:

```
var group = L.geoJson(/* stuff */);

function attachPopupsToStuff(layer) {
    layer.bindPopup('Hello');
}

group.eachLayer(attachPopupsToStuff);
```

Note that `eachFeature` iterates on the existing instances of `L.Layer`, and **not** on the original GeoJSON `feature`s. As implied in the [`L.GeoJSON` example in the documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-example), each `L.Layer` created through `L.GeoJSON` has a copy of the feature that originated it, in its `feature` property, e.g.:

```
var group = L.geoJson(/* stuff */);

group.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.name);
});
```